# ionic3 GET http://localhost:8100/null 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Don't know why always showing this error for me, but ionic3 project can run as usual.

This is what showing:
[image][image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Please add some more code so we can point the exact cause of the error, but given that description, seems like you're including an image somewhere in any of your pages, and the `src` of that image is being set dynamically after getting some information from the server, something like

```
<img [src]="imageUrl">
```

where `imageUrl` is a property from the component code.

The problem is that this `imageUrl` is null when Angular tries to load the page, so the source of the image is `null` (that's why you get the 404 when trying to get an image from `http:localhost:8100/null`; that ending `null` is because that property is `null` when the image element is being created in the view).

You could prevent that error by adding an additional check, like

```
<img *ngIf="imageUrl" [src]="imageUrl">
```

so the image will only be added if the source is ready.

Comment: Thank you, this was annoying me for quite some time.

Comment: Thanks, this solves my problem as well! It works also even if src is loaded async

Comment: this is also occurred in ionic4 and solved my problem in ionic4. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add this & it will solve your query `<img *ngIf="imageUrl" [src]="imageUrl">`

Answer (score 0):

I am using ionic 4 angular
<img *ngIf="imageUrl" src="{{imageUrl}}">
is works for fine for me.

Comment: Please don't make "me too" answers. Plus, you missed []

Comment: This the same answer as https://stackoverflow.com/a/51513057/5468463 but incorectly used src, should be [src] or {{imageUrl}}

Comment: Thank you.for correcting me. Yeah it will be <img *ngIf="imageUrl" src="{{imageUrl}}">

Answer (score 0):

```
<img [src]="imageUrl || 'assets/images/defaultimage.png' ">
```

Comment: Please add more details to support your post.